# How to prove $\sum_{n=2} ^\infty\left( \frac1 {S_{n-1}}-\frac1 {S_{n}}\right)$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $S_{n}$  partial sums of $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty a_{n}$ that its a positive series

How to prove that

$$\sum_{n=2} ^\infty\left( \frac1 {S_{n-1}}-\frac1 {S_{n}}\right)$$

is convergent

Comment: Where you write "that its a positive series," do you mean "where all the $a_k$'s are positive"?

Comment: yes @Barry Cipra

Comment: Then consider two cases, when $S_n$ diverges and when $S_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

This is a telescoping sum, so:

$$\sum_{n=2} ^m\left( \frac1 {S_{n-1}}-\frac1 {S_{n}}\right)=\frac{1}{S_1}-\frac{1}{S_m}$$

If $S_n$ converges, does this converge as $m\to \infty?$

If $S_n$ diverges, does this converge as $m\to\infty$?

Why do you need $a_n$ are positive (other than that the formula is undefined if any $S_n$ is zero?)

Comment: i think that we need prove 1/Sm is converge and because Sm partial sums of positive series that mean that its monotone series to 0 that means that its bounded so 1/sm is converge .

Comment: Right, so $S_m$ is a monotone increasing and positive sequence, so $\frac{1}{S_m}$ is a monotone positive decreasing sequence, and hence must converge to some value $\geq 0$.

Comment: so is that enough to prove it ?

Answer (score 0):

$\sum (\frac{1}{S_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{S_{n}})$ is convergent means $\frac{1}{S_{n-1}}$ and $\frac{1}{S_{n}}$ converge or diverge together. It means

[Assuming $a_n$ > 0 so that S_n is not zero convergent]

case 1 - if $S_n$ converges,say $S_n \to l$ then $\sum (\frac{1}{S_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{S_{n}}) = \sum(1/l - 1/l ) \to 0$ ie., convergent

case 2 - if $S_n \to \infty$ then $\frac {1}{S_n} \to 0$, so  $\sum (\frac{1}{S_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{S_{n}}) = 0$